# Decision making factors for migrating SSAS from Azure VM to Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, ssas-tabular

Recently we have upgraded our SSAS resources. Currently our SSAS is on Azure VM costing us based on this VM type 'Standard E32-8s_v3'.

I am looking for a way to save more cost by selecting a better option.

What can be a good option to save cost and at the same time have better efficiency.

what factors/ differences can be considered if we go to Azure analysis services instead of SSAS on Azure VM.

Our SQL server is also on Azure VM.

We have our reports on Power BI report server and SSRS.

Data is coming from different resources like SAP, external parties etc using SSIS.

Can you please Advice/ Suggest a better options for our data architecture.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your VM is 8 cores and 256GB RAM.

One factor in pricing you haven’t mentioned is SQL licensing. You didn’t specify whether you are renting the SQL license with the VM or bringing your own license and what that costs. I’m going to assume you are renting it. With Azure Analysis Services the license is included in the price.

In Azure Analysis Services 100QPU is roughly equivalent to 5 cores. So 200QPU (an S2) would be an equivalent amount of CPU and a [similar price](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/analysis-services/) but only has 50GB RAM.

To get the equivalent amount of RAM the S8 would get you close (200GB RAM) but for substantially more cost.

If you have one large model which (at least during peak usage or processing) uses most of the 256GB RAM then it may be tough to move to Azure Analysis Services for a similar price. If you have several models on that one server then you could split them across several smaller Azure Analysis Services servers and it may be a reasonable price for you. Or you could scale up for processing when RAM is needed most and scale down for the rest of the day to save cost.

Comment: We have our own SQL licence for SQL Server.